# Very slowly SQL JOIN Query (Didn't finish)

Tags: sql, performance, mariadb

I have a very slow query:

```
SELECT
t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_ean,
t2.den,
t2.hodina,
sum(CASE 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 5' 
    AND aktualizace_ciselniku_teplotni_oblast = 'Region Jižní Čechy' THEN t2.tdd_tdd5jiznicechy * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 5' 
    AND aktualizace_ciselniku_teplotni_oblast = 'Region Jižní Morava' THEN t2.tdd_tdd5jiznimorava * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 5' 
    AND aktualizace_ciselniku_teplotni_oblast = 'Region Praha' THEN t2.tdd_tdd5praha * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 5' 
    AND aktualizace_ciselniku_teplotni_oblast = 'Region Severní Čechy' THEN t2.tdd_tdd5severnicechy * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 5' 
    AND aktualizace_ciselniku_teplotni_oblast = 'Region Severní Morava' THEN t2.tdd_tdd5severnimorava * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 5' 
    AND aktualizace_ciselniku_teplotni_oblast = 'Region Střední Čechy' THEN t2.tdd_tdd5strednicechy * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 5' 
    AND aktualizace_ciselniku_teplotni_oblast = 'Region Východní Čechy' THEN t2.tdd_tdd5vychodnicechy * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 5' 
    AND aktualizace_ciselniku_teplotni_oblast = 'Region Západní Čechy' THEN t2.tdd_tdd5zapadnicechy * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 1' THEN t2.tdd_tdd1cr * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 2' THEN t2.tdd_tdd2cr * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 3' THEN t2.tdd_tdd3cr * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 4' THEN t2.tdd_tdd4cr * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 6' THEN t2.tdd_tdd6cr * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 7' THEN t2.tdd_tdd7cr * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'TDD č. 8' THEN t2.tdd_tdd8cr * t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
    ELSE 0 
   END) AS aktualizace_ciselniku_odhad_rocni_spotreby 
  FROM
aktualizace_ciselniku t1 
 JOIN
normalizovane_tdd t2 
    ON t2.den >= t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_datum_od 
    AND t2.den <= t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_datum_do 
GROUP BY
t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_ean,
t2.den,
t2.hodina 
ORDER BY
NULL;
```

[Here is](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=44e1c4215f875b43e4c8654e18f9ad2c) link to dbfiddle.

In table aktualizace_ciselniku is about 40 000 rows and in normalizovane_tdd about 8000 rows but query after 1 hour didnt get result.

How to optimize it ? Creating index or do 2 SQL commands in one query ?

Database type MariaDB connection via php mysqli_connect.

Comment: Is the PHP tag relevant?  Also you may want to add the tag for the type of database you are using (mysql for example)

Comment: I edited post, Database type is MariaDB connection via php mysqli_connect

Comment: I would suggest that you ask a new question.  Simplify the query to just get a simple version that illustrates the performance problem (perhaps `select count(*) from . . .`).  Explain what the columns are and what the logic is that you want to implement.  The sample data is quite hard to follow particularly for someone who doesn't speak your native language.

Comment: In your dbfiddle, there are no indexes declared. If this reflects the reality, then it probably answers your question. You should at least have indexes on the columns used in your JOIN: `ON t2.den >= t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_datum_od 
    AND t2.den <= t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_datum_do`, in both tables